# How to get logcat crashes

Tags: android, tags, logcat

A newbie logcat question here, I am sure this is well known but could not find the answer. Sorry.

I want to use logcat for the users of my app `MyApp` to email me crash reports that obviously I don't know where they will appear. I want to print Warning and above only for my app.

I read the [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#outputFormat), and understood that, to print logcat only for a package I should do something like:

```
 logcat -d -v time MyApp:W *:S
```

However that does not work: that is just for tags, not for app names.

I read people suggesting something like

```
logcat -d -v time *:W | grep MyApp
```

but that does not work either: the error messages, exactly what I am interested in, do not print `MyApp` name in all the lines.

I also tried

```
logcat -d -v time --pid=$(pidof -s MyApp) *:W
```

but that does not work either since the app crashed already, so it is not running, and it will send me the log of the still running `MyApp` PID.

What I ended up doing was to print only the last 20 minutes of everything with:

```
long timesinceepoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - 1200;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v time -t "+timesinceepoch+".0 *:W");
```

but I still get lots of trash and big files, of course.

So how do I add a MyApp tag to **ALL** the logcat logs of `MyApp`?

**EDIT:** Actually, in Android Studio the `MyApp` appears in the logcat, and there is an option to show logcat for a single app. Isn't Android Studio logcat and adb logcat the same??

Comment: You can also use an already existing solution: [https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics)

Comment: Thanks, I have no doubt it would work, but it is a huge cannon to attack a very simple issue, specially if studio knows which package issue each line of message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally unnecessary since when an app calls `logcat` it only logs the calling app logs. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157/does-access-to-logcat-need-root/7260#7260) (thanks @jake-lee !).